# Is my loop logic wrong or is it my query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I have a couple nested loops in php to produce something like this:

[image: Cost table screenshot]

My problem lies either with this query:

```
$cost_inner_query = "SELECT Cost_Center_Category.Cost_Center_Category_Name, 
        Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Number AS l, Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Name, 
        Locations.Location_Abbrev, Locations.Location, Cost_Category.Cost_Category_Name, Cost_Planning.*  
        FROM Cost_Centers 
        LEFT JOIN Cost_Center_Category 
        ON Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Category = Cost_Center_Category.Cost_Center_Category_ID 
        LEFT JOIN Locations 
        ON Cost_Centers.Location = Locations.Location_Abbrev 
        LEFT JOIN Cost_Planning 
        ON Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Number = Cost_Planning.Cost_Center_Number
        LEFT JOIN Cost_Category 
        ON Cost_Planning.Cost_Category = Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID
        WHERE Cost_Centers.Location = '$cost_current_location'
        AND Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID = $cost_current_ccr
        AND Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Category = $cost_current_ccc_id;";
```

or my loop structure:

```
foreach($cost_loc_results as $cost_loc){ //loop to populate data table with locations
        $cost_CC_results = array();
        echo '<tr align="right" class="cost_loc"><td class="plus_minus" width="20" align="center" bordercolor="#000000"
            style="cursor:pointer;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">+</td>
            <td width="20" align="left" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#00FFFF"
            style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].'</td> 
            <td width="120" align="left" 
            bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;
            border-right-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt" >'.$cost_loc['Location'].'</td>
            <td width="50" align="left" 
            bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;
            border-right-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt" >'.$cost_loc['Hours'].'</td>
            <td width="50" align="left" 
            bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;
            border-right-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt" >'.$cost_loc['LC'].'</td>
            <td width="50" align="left" 
            bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;
            border-right-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt" >'.$cost_loc['FX'].'</td>';
        for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ 
            if($i%2 == 0){
                echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';

            }
        }
        echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>';
        for($i=10; $i<20; $i++){
            if($i%2 == 0){
                echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';

            }
        }
        foreach ($cost_category_results as $ccr){
            echo '<tr align="right" class="ccr" style="display:none;"><td class="plus_minus" width="20" align="center" bordercolor="#000000"
            style="cursor:pointer;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">-</td>
            <td colspan="5" width="20" align="left" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#a8fff3"
            style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">'.$ccr['Cost_Category_Name'].'</td>';
            for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
                if($i%2 == 0){
                    echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$ccr['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$ccr['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                }
            }
            echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>';
            for($i=10; $i<20; $i++){
                if($i%2 == 0){
                    echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$ccr['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$ccr['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                }
            } 

            foreach($cost_CCC_results as $cost_ccc){
                $cost_inner_results    = array();
                $cost_current_location = $cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'];
                $cost_current_ccc_id   = $cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_ID'];
                $cost_current_ccr      = $ccr['Cost_Category_ID'];
                echo '<tr align="right" class="cost_ccc" style="display:none;"><td width="20" align="center"
                    style="font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;"></td>
                    <td colspan="5"width="150" align="left"
                    bgcolor="#FFCC00" 
                    style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;
                    border-right-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:
                    solid;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:
                    1pt;border-bottom-width:1pt">'.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].'</td>';
                for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
                    if($i%2 == 0){
                        echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                    }
                }
                echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>';
                for($i=10; $i<20; $i++){
                    if($i%2 == 0){
                        echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#e3e4e5" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<td id="Sum'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$i.'" bgcolor="#b2b2b2" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt"></td>';
                    }
                }
                $cost_inner_query = "SELECT Cost_Center_Category.Cost_Center_Category_Name, 
                            Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Number AS l, Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Name, 
                            Locations.Location_Abbrev, Locations.Location, Cost_Category.Cost_Category_Name, Cost_Planning.*  
                            FROM Cost_Centers 
                            LEFT JOIN Cost_Center_Category 
                            ON Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Category = Cost_Center_Category.Cost_Center_Category_ID 
                            LEFT JOIN Locations 
                            ON Cost_Centers.Location = Locations.Location_Abbrev 
                            LEFT JOIN Cost_Planning 
                            ON Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Number = Cost_Planning.Cost_Center_Number
                            LEFT JOIN Cost_Category 
                            ON Cost_Planning.Cost_Category = Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID
                            WHERE Cost_Centers.Location = '$cost_current_location'
                            AND Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID = $cost_current_ccr
                            AND Cost_Centers.Cost_Center_Category = $cost_current_ccc_id;";

                $cost_inner_result = $mysqli->query($cost_inner_query); 

                while($row = $cost_inner_result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $cost_inner_results[] = $row;
                }
                foreach($cost_inner_results as $cost_inner){
                    echo '<tr class="inner" style="display:none;"><td> </td><td bordercolor="#000000" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">
                    '.$cost_inner['l'].'</td>
                    <td bordercolor="#000000" colspan="4" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">'.$cost_inner['Cost_Center_Name'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td name="LC'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_inner['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$cost_inner['Cost_Center_Name'].'2015Q1" id="LC'.$cost_loc['Location_Abbrev'].''.$cost_inner['Cost_Category_Name'].''.$cost_ccc['Cost_Center_Category_Name'].''.$cost_inner['Cost_Center_Name'].'2015Q1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" width="20" style="font-size:8pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt;display:none" contenteditable="true">'.$cost_inner['2015_Q_1'].'</td>';
//past this point it just continues doing this for all <td>'s in the table.
```

I know it's a lot of code I just posted there but the gist is that I use nested loops to form Location rows, then Cost Category rows, Cost Center Category rows, and then Cost Center rows. (I know, the naming of these is confusing)
What happens with my current query above is that in the innermost loop that forms the Cost Center rows (the rows with all the data), the only rows that show up are the ones that match the query, the ones where  `Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID = $cost_current_ccr`. 
Illustrated here in the bottom table:

[image: help me]

which is technically correct, but what I want to happen is similar to the the top table displayed: I want the rows that match to populate the data table to the right, but if there is no match, I still want the cost center to be displayed.

I've tried omitting the first AND clause from my `$cost_inner_query`, that populates all the cost centers but doesn't match the data correctly.

Is my query the thing that needs to be changed or is it the loop structure, or something else like the database structure?

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN Cost_Category...  WHERE Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID = $cost_current_ccr` is the same as `INNER JOIN Cost_Category`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight flaw in your query, as I mentioned in my comment.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT x.Cost_Center_Category_Name
     , y.Cost_Center_Number 
     , y.Cost_Center_Name
     , l.Location_Abbrev
     , l.Location
     , z.Cost_Category_Name
     , p.*  
  FROM Cost_Centers y
  LEFT 
  JOIN Cost_Center_Category x
    ON c.Cost_Center_Category_ID = y.Cost_Center_Category 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Locations l
    ON l.Location_Abbrev = y.Location
  LEFT 
  JOIN Cost_Planning p
    ON p.Cost_Center_Number = y.Cost_Center_Number
  LEFT 
  JOIN Cost_Category z
    ON z.Cost_Category_ID = p.Cost_Category
   AND z.Cost_Category_ID = $cost_current_ccr
 WHERE y.Location = '$cost_current_location'
   AND y.Cost_Center_Category = $cost_current_ccc_id
```

Because your code beginning with the line `foreach($cost_CCC_results as $cost_ccc){` is incomplete, it's hard to identify further errors.

That said, I'm glad I don't have to maintain a database employing this naming policy - nor manage variables as subtly different as '$cost_CC_results' and '$cost_CCC_results'

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code now. And I tried your query, there was an error that said `call to member function fetch assoc() on boolean` so there may be something wrong.

Comment: There's no syntax error in what I've written, but we'd need to see the echo of your version to be sure. Also, take a look at prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah it's not your code I don't think, I think it actually may be a database thing, there's not a relationship between cost_center_category and cost_category. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand what you want, becase your code is incomplete.

But, try doing this:

1) Add `Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID` to be returned in in your SELECT fields. For example:

```
SELECT 
    ....
    Cost_Category.Cost_Category_ID, 
    ....
FROM Cost_Centers
....
```

2) Add this code after the end of `foreach($cost_CCC_results as $cost_ccc){`:

```
if (count($cost_CCC_results) == 0) {
    echo '<tr align="right" class="cost_ccc" style="display:none;">';
    echo '<td>' . $ccr['Cost_Category_ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

With this, you should have a blank line with the Cost Center displayed, even if there are no matches.